# Application exit even not firing in c# windows application

Tags: c#

I am using the below class to hide and show the windows task bar.
I am calling the the class like below.

Problem : when i start the application, the taskbar is hiding perfectly.
But when i exit the application by stopping the debugging, the task bar is 
not showing up. I mean the application exit is not firing in my code.
I need such a way like, whatever the way i close my application, it shud 
finially show the tashbar() before exiting.

Please help. Thanks.

PROGRAM :

---

```
static class Program
{

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Taskbar.Hide();
        Form1 TargerForm = new Form1();
        Application.ApplicationExit += new EventHandler(Application_ApplicationExit);
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.Run(TargerForm);
    }
    static void Application_ApplicationExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Taskbar.Show();
    }
}
```

CLASS :

---

```
public class Taskbar
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int FindWindow(string className, string windowText);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int ShowWindow(int hwnd, int command);

    public const int SW_HIDE = 0;
    public const int SW_SHOW = 1;

    public int _taskbarHandle;
    protected static int Handle
    {
        get
        {
            return FindWindow("Shell_TrayWnd", "");
        }
    }

    public Taskbar()
    {
        _taskbarHandle = FindWindow("Shell_TrayWnd", "");
    }

    public static void Show()
    {
        ShowWindow(Handle, SW_SHOW);
    }

    public static void Hide()
    {
        ShowWindow(Handle, SW_HIDE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just call Taskbar.Show() after the call to Application.Run? Application.Run will block until the form is closed.

Your code could look like this:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Taskbar.Hide();
    Form1 TargerForm = new Form1();
    Application.ApplicationExit += new EventHandler(Application_ApplicationExit);
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.Run(TargerForm);
    Taskbar.Show();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean, "still no solutions"? Taskbar.Show() will execute when the TargetForm is finished running. Come to think of it, one line that looks funny is the App.Run line, it should look like Application.Run(new TargetForm())

Answer (score 0):

When you stop debugging, that's a "rude" exit to a program, and nothing fires after that.  MSFT's own Visual Studio integrated web browser suffers from this too.  If this is super important to you, you might want to consider running something in the background which takes care of this cleanup for you and doesn't run in the context of the debugger?

I don't think there's a way to capture a "stop debugging" event, but I'd love to be proven wrong :)

Comment: @Dave Markle, it sounds wiered.
There shud be some solution for this. I guess.
why this is the rude way of exiting the application. Do i have any other good practice to stop the running application ?
Thanks.

Comment: Why not put an exit button on your form? And then inside the click event handler call ApplicationExit?

Comment: @Jason Down, my appliction is running on a thread.
Its a background job. No forms are there in the app.
The only way to exit the thread is to kill it in task manager.
Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is "TargerForm" supposed to be doing? What context are you using your Taskbar class?

Comment: I create instance of a form for starting the application.
I am using this form as a taskbar in my desktop. It is just a taskbar, to show the application opened and swap between the applications.
This is the reason for me to hide the windows defaust task bar, because i have my own task bar and i dont want the users to access windows.
I hope u got the point for doing this....
Thanks.