# Exit Event in a Windows Forms Application?

Tags: c#, winforms

Yeah I know - one of the following lines will do this usually:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += OnApplicationExit;
Application.ApplicationExit += OnApplicationExit;

void OnApplicationExit(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs) { ... }
```

But what when one don't use any forms **in a WinForms application**? To make it a *hidden* windows application - which is not a service. Both of the above examples don't work for me.

This is how I start my WinForms app. As you can see I don't pass any form to the [`Run`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.run%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method

```
public static void Main()
{
    InitMyApp();
    // Here I tried to subscribe to the above shown events => didn't work.
    Application.Run();
}
```

Comment: `AppDomain.ProcessExit` works fine for me in a console application (i.e. no forms). Your example shows no attempt to use _either_ method. Please include [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly illustrates your question.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Well there is no way to make a hidden console application - AFAIK. That's the reason why I've asked especially for WinForms. Create a WinForms Project and remove the content of `Main()` and just do `Application.Run()` => it will run - but *hidden*. Updated my question to make things hopefully more clear

Comment: These might help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20675024/when-will-appdomain-processexit-not-get-called and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157009/application-exit-even-not-firing-in-c-sharp-windows-application

Comment: I guess it depends on your definition of "hidden". That said, my point was mainly that a) the `ProcessExit` event seems to work fine regardless, and b) if you don't post code showing how _you_ are trying to use `ProcessExit`, no one can help you figure out how _to fix that code_.

Answer (score 0):

Thread.GetDomain().ProcessExit worked on this end.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Test
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            Thread.GetDomain ().ProcessExit += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
                Console.WriteLine ("Foo!");
            };
            BackgroundWorker autokill = new BackgroundWorker ();
            autokill.DoWork += (object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) => {
                Thread.Sleep (5000);
                Environment.Exit (0);
            };
            autokill.RunWorkerAsync ();
            Application.Run ();
        }
    }
}
```